# Error) Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {success})

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Data is work normally uploaded to Firebase, but this error occurs on the web

**Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {success}).
If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

Please tell me the cause of this error How can I get rid of the error

**Add Button(onClick)**

```
  const handleClick = async () => {
    const product = {
      id,
      imageUrl,
      title,
      category,
      price: price * quantity,
      size: selected,
      quantity,
    };
    // setProduct({ ...product, price: price * quantity, size: selected, quantity });
    addToItem.mutate(product, {
      onSuccess: () => {
        setSuccess("장바구니에 추가되었습니다.");
        setTimeout(() => setSuccess(null), 3000);
      },
    });
  };
```

**Firebase Add function**

```
export async function addToCart(uid, product) {
  const carts = collection(db, "users", "user", `${uid}`, "userCart", "carts");
  await addDoc(
    carts,
    {
      ...product,
      id: product.id,
      imageUrl: product.imageUrl,
      title: product.title,
      price: product.price,
      category: product.category,
      size: product.size,
      quantity: product.quantity,
    },
    { merge: true }
  );
}
```

**React-Query Mutation**

```
export default function useCart() {
  const { uid } = useAuthContext();
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  const addToItem= useMutation((product) => addToCart(uid, product), {
    onSuccess: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries(["carts", uid]);
    },
  });
...

  return { addToItem, ... };
}
```

Comment: It tells you what the error is. You are trying to render an object. It has nothing to do with the code you provided. The problem is somewhere where you render stuff, not in the action callbacks